# Why does dismiss modal resets my view to the top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My problem is a following I have a created a page of data where there is a button. Where you can press for more info about the data and that opens a bootstrap modal. But when I close the modal I am back at the top of my page.
Is there away when I close the modal am back at the data I pressed instead of the top.

Can that be done by teleporting my view to these specified div id? Or is just that I need to prevent something?

This is my Jquery code to open the modal:

```
var getThisCoinToPopUp = function () {
    $('#showThisCoin').modal({
        show: 'false',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
};

var init = function () {
    $('.container #info').on('click', 'a', getThisCoinToPopUp);
};
$(document).ready(init());
```

Comment: Are you using an `a` tag with an `href` attribute with a hashbang (`#`) value? If so, add `return false` to the end of that code block that is responsible for dismissing the pop-up.

Comment: Yes it is a tag but the parent has a # value. I have solved the problem but thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it I just need to add

```
e.preventDefault()
```

to the function like this:

```
var getThisCoinToPopUp = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#showThisCoin').modal({
        show: 'false',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
};
```

Comment: you could also change the href value to javascript:void(0)

Comment: How do you mean? I don't understand what you mean with javascript:void(0)

Comment: instead of href='#' you can use href='javascript:void(0)'